# How to repeat last substitution of Insert Mode in VIM?

Tags: vim, repeat, insertion

Consider I changed a word to "Next" (`cwNext`<kbd>ESC</kbd>). After this I do, say, change till semi-colon (`cf;`). At this point, I want the previous substitution (Next) to be inserted here. Is this a way to do this? I think there is a way to do it!

The point is with any subsequent edits invoked by different means (like `6S`, `cf;`, `3cw`, etc), I want the insertion done in the first instance to be repeated.

Comment: vim editor questions should be asked on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ From the vim tag: For non-programming questions please use https://vi.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I was not aware.... will take care next time. And if it can be moved there now, I don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That last insert can be repeated using <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> (see [`:help i_CTRL-A`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-A)). Pressing `cf;<C-A>` will insert "Next" over everything including the next semi-colon. This solution was pointed out by user [yolenover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3271687/yolenoyer), all credits go to them.

The last change is also stored in the `.` (dot) register (see [`:help quote.`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote.)).
If you want to avoid pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, you could also visual-select the text to the semi-colon and then put the contents of the dot register using `vf;".p`.

Comment: `<C-A>` can be used instead of `<C-R>.`

Comment: Thanks ... this worked. <C-@> is more useful when to exit INSERT mode. I am not able to understand <C-R>; I tried but it did not work. The document states that you need to then enter the register from where you want to put. Nevertheless, this has helped. Thanks

Comment: @JitendraLoyal I had this in my first version of my answer. You can specify the dot register by pressing `<C-R>.` (Ctrl-R followed by dot). This does the same as `<C-A>` at the expense of an additional key press.

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich... got it ... I missed the dot! I highly appreciate your response.